# Im new with arduino and I made this function

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

it does this error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive] how do I fix this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNR0R.png)

Comment: you should [paste code into question as text instead of as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question),

Comment: you should also post the entire error message that you get from your IDE as text, not a small part of it.

Comment: i tried to paste your code in my IDE to see where the error is but my IDE doesn't support pasting images of code into it.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or links to images of code. Put the code itself in your question as text, formatted as a code sample. Using images makes it your code difficult to work with.

Comment: alright I'll keep that in mind for next time thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Arduino uses C++ language, The reason for the error: " invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' " is that the function `Serial.readStringUntill()` returns a **String**, but you are trying to equate it with a character in `myList=='A'`(anything encased in `'` is considered character in C++) , you can fix the error by accessing first character from the 'myList' and then equate like shown below

```
myList[0]=='A'
```

Comment: `Serial.readStringUntil()` does not return a `const char*`, it return a [String](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Stream.h#L108). A `String` is not a `const char *`.  `String.c_str()` however return a `const char*` (pointer to an immutable char array). See [this](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/).